# Sort a dictionary 'd' by d.values(), then by length of the corresponding keys

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I want to obtain a reversed order of a dictionary with two constraints. Firstly, I sort according to the values:

```
>>> d = {'I C': (2, 4), 'B I C': (2, 6), 'B I': (2, 6)}
>>> sortd = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)    (1)
>>> sortd
[('B I', (2, 6)), ('B I C', (2, 6)), ('I C', (2, 4))]
```

Secondly I want to obtain, for items with same values, the one with the longest key before. With my previous example, I want this as result:

```
[('B I C', (2, 6)), ('B I', (2, 6)), ('I C', (2, 4))]
```

Is it possible to do it directly in my `sorted()` command (1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Include the length of the key in your sort function:

```
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: (v[1], len(v[0])), reverse=True)
```

output:

```
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda v: (v[1], len(v[0])), reverse=True)
[('B I C', (2, 6)), ('B I', (2, 6)), ('I C', (2, 4))]
```

So each item is sorted on the tuple `(value, len(key))`; a shorter length is reverse sorted after a longer length, but only if the first element of the tuple is the same.